# Not able to delete EditText content in one go ,when user longpress the backspace on softkeypad

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText. I am using this for entering the mobile number of different countries. As soon as the user starts entering the number , i start formatting it based on the country of the number . For example for indian number i show it as 
98765 43210 , i.e a space after fifth character. Similarly for other countries i use different formatting patterns.

But at the time of deleting the number from the keypad i am facing an issue. When the user clicks backspace on softkeypad , one character gets deleted.As i am overriding the AfterTextChanged method of EditText , so it gets called . In this method i check if the formatting is disturbed due to erasing the character . And i try to reformat the remaining number , and set the reformatted text again on edittext. This works properly.

But when user longpresses the backspace in order to delete the entire phone number in one go ,Then there is a problem as described below:

Keypad's backspace is pressed (So focus is on keypad), one character got deleted, AfterTextChanged got called , In AfterTextChanged method, I reformatted the text and set the reformatted text again on edittext using editText.setText(String), As i set the text, focus went to edittext , keypad lost the focus .so keypad is no longer pressed. (I can see the keypad backspace getting unpressed on UI after one character is deleted. Even though i have not lifted the my finger from backspace) 
As a result it deleted only one character and stopped.

I know if the donot set the reformatted text on the editText in AfterTextChanged, then longpress will work and is working. But i need to set this text to show dynamic formatting of number .

But i also want to delete the phone number in one go , when the user longpresses the backspace of softkeypad.
Please help me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setOnLongClickListener or compare your character length once the backspace is pressed to the previous value and ignore your AfterTextChanged event?

Comment: can you please elaborate the comparing the length solution. I do not understand what exactly are you suggesting .

Comment: Basically if you new length is less than your old length then skip the formatting.

Comment: But suppose the user entered 11digits initially. Since in india 11 digit numbers are not valid ,so it will look like 98765432109 . i.e no space in between . Now user pressed backspace and deleted last character i.e 9 . Now number remains 9876543210 which needs formatting . It has to be shown like 98765 43210 .

Comment: so if i use your approach i will skip formatting in this case as current length < previous length .

Comment: Ok, how about only doing the formating when the user leaves the edittext using the OnFocusChangeListener and doing your formating on (!hasFocus) ?

Comment: not working on setting the text when the edittext has lost focus . 
Because in that case the formatting is not happening.